# Angularjs- The view is not updating as data is changed

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. Implemented a small app which list quotes from the server.

On the page I have a button to list the quotes. User clicking it, the list are shown obtaining it from the server. Also in the same page, there is option to add new quotes, which is button on clicking it shows the text area to enter the new quote and shows the save & clear buttons.

All this is working fine.

On entering the new quote and clicking on the save, save is happening on the backend (db), but the list is not updating showing the newly added quote. 
This is the `saveQuote` function:

```
$scope.saveQuote = function () {
  $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  var fh = new FormHelper();
  if ($scope.quoteId) {
    fh.append("quoteId", $scope.quoteId);
  }
  fh.append("description", $scope.description);
  $http.post("http://localhost:8080/VL1.1/saveQuote", fh.data).
  success(function (response) {
    alert("in save quote");
    $scope.quote.description = $scope.description;
    upDatedQuoteList(response, "save quotes");
    //$scope.quotelist=response.quotelist;
  });
};

 //$scope.$watch('quotelist')

function FormHelper() {
  this.data = "";
  this.append = function (name, val) {
    if (this.data.length > 0) {
      this.data += "&";
    }
    this.data += encodeURIComponent(name);
    this.data += "=";
    this.data += encodeURIComponent(val);
  };
};
```

This is the upDatedQuoteList function:

```
function upDatedQuoteList(response, msg) { 
    alert(msg); 
    $scope.quotelist=response.quotelist; 
    if($scope.quotelist.length > 0) { 
        alert("setting showlist"); 
        $scope.showlist= true; 
    } 
};
```

Some alerts to check the flow. Pl ignore them.

And this is the view template

```
<div ng-show="showlist">
<table border="1" border-collapse="true">
    <tr class="even">
        <th style="width:20px; word-wrap: break-word;">Sl No</th>
        <th style="width:800px; word-wrap: break-word;">Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in quotelist" >
        <td style="width:20px; word-wrap: break-word;">{{ $index+1 }}</td>
        <td style="width:800px; word-wrap: break-word;" >{{ x.description }}</td>
        <td style="width:20px; word-wrap: break-word;"><button ng-click="editQuote(x)">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Your help is highly solicited.

Comment: Please post also the upDatedQuoteList() function body, since we don't see how are you trying to update the $scope.quotelist variable with the newly added quote, as @Dominique Canlas stated.

Comment: Here is the update function                                                             function upDatedQuoteList(response, msg)
  {
   alert(msg);
   $scope.quotelist=response.quotelist;
   if($scope.quotelist.length > 0)
   {  
    alert("setting showlist");
    $scope.showlist= true;
   }
  };

Comment: Ok, it seems that you update the `$scope.quotelist` variable from the Ajax response. Now can you also post the response returned from the server? I mean, the `response` object? In browsers like Firefox or Chrome you can use the debug tools to monitor the Ajax request/response messages. There you can find what is being returned in the response. Also check if the rseponse type is JSON.

Comment: I am sure the response is a JSON, because JSON is what is returned when I initially click list quotes in the page. I really do not know how to check for response in chrome, will give a try and get back....